# Page elements not hovering correctly, no consistency across browsers

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have an area on a web page where there is a date entry.  Next to it is a button that if clicked, should pop up a little calendar to the right of the entry allowing users to click on the desired date.

I want the calendar to pop up and not interrupt the flow of the page whatsoever.  Here is the style for the calendar:

```
div.dateEntry
{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 25px;
    left: 365px;
}
```

In Firefox, the calendar pops up in the correct area, but it interrupts the page flow pushing everything below the calendar entry down.  In IE, the calendar displays in its static as if no style is being applied.  What gives?

Comment: Are you using a reset stylesheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want is to position that element `absolute` **instead** of `relative` as that will remove it from the document flow

It may need it's "parent" set to `position:relative;` in order to make sure it still pops up beside the date entry element